# TFTP uploads failing

Tags: linux, centos, selinux, tftp

I am running TFTPD via xinetd on a Centos 5.4 server.  I am able to access files via tftp fine, so I know the service is running ok.  However, whenever I try and upload a file I get a 0 Permission denied message.

I have already created the file in /tftpboot and set the permissions to 666.

My tftpd config has verbose logging (-vvvv), but all I see in my /var/log/messages is:

START: tftp pid=20383 from=192.168.77.4

I have seen some mention that SELinux can prevent TFTPD uploads, but I'd expect to see something in the logs.  I have SELinux set in permissive mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok - I've now tested running outside of xinetd using the following command:

in.tftpd -l -c -v -u root -s /tftpboot

This seems to work ok.  However, when running with the following xinetd config, which I believe does the same thing, I get the same error with writing files.

Comment: Aha - a bit of a breakthrough.  I installed auditd, and things started to appear in the audit log relating to tftp.  I then used grep tftp /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M tftpwrite to generate a SELinux rule to allow tftp to write.  I then applied this with semodule -i tftpwrite.pp and restarted xinetd.

Now I am able to save over existing files, which gets me some of the way there.

I am still unable to create new files, despite the presence of the -c flag in the config for xinetd.  Would be nice to be able to create from network devices saving their config via TFTP.

Comment: Nice discussion on some of this here - http://grimwell.wikispaces.com/tftpd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Followed the info at http://grimwell.wikispaces.com/tftpd, paying particular attention to "rinse and repeat" in order to get the selinux policies in place.  After a few attempts it all started working - uploading, and creation of new files.

In short:

- make sure you have audit installed in centos otherwise SELinux may not log anything!
- make sure your xinetd.d/tftpd has `-c -v -s /tftpboot` in the server args line
- make sure that the directory tftp will be writing to has 777 permissions
- do a tftp localhost and try to put a file in the directory
- touch a file in the directoy, chmod 666 it, and then via tftp localhost, try and overwrite the file
- do `grep tftp /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m tftpwrite` to create a selinux policy.  Make sure that the policy includes write and create lines.  If not, try writing and creating again to generate alerts in the audit log and try again.
- create an installable policy using `grep tftp /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M tftpwrite` then install it using `semodule -i tftpwrite.pp`
- `service xinetd reload` and try using tftp.

Splendid.  Hope others find this useful!

Answer (score 4):

I found another, better solution to this problem.  I couldn't believe that the people who wrote the selinux policy files didn't think that people would need tftp uploads so I did some digging.  I couldn't find anything on the internet that isn't already referenced here but by searching the selinux policy I was able to find another security context already on the system for tftp writes.  Changing the context of /tftpboot fixed the problem.

```
# sesearch -a | grep tftpdir  |grep tftpd_
   allow tftpd_t tftpdir_t : file { read getattr }; 
   allow tftpd_t tftpdir_t : dir { read getattr search }; 
   allow tftpd_t tftpdir_t : lnk_file { read getattr }; 
   allow tftpd_t tftpdir_rw_t : file { ioctl read write create getattr setattr lock append unlink link rename }; 
   allow tftpd_t tftpdir_rw_t : dir { ioctl read write create getattr setattr lock unlink link rename add_name remove_name reparent search rmdir }; 
   allow tftpd_t tftpdir_rw_t : lnk_file { read create getattr setattr unlink link rename }; 
# ls -Z /tftpboot/ -a
drwxrwxrwx  root root system_u:object_r:tftpdir_t      .
drwxr-xr-x  root root system_u:object_r:root_t         ..
# chcon -t tftpdir_rw_t /tftpboot
# ls -Z /tftpboot/ -a
drwxrwxrwx  root root system_u:object_r:tftpdir_rw_t   .
drwxr-xr-x  root root system_u:object_r:root_t         ..
```

Comment: Nice digging!  Would it be necessary to do the same procedure for subdirectories of tftpboot?

Answer (score 3):

Are you starting tftpd with the -s option?  Some clients may be expecting this, e.g. uploading a file called `foo` to `/foo` is really intended for `/tftpboot/foo` on the server.  Adding `-s /tftpboot` essentially tells the server to do a "chroot" to that directory.

Try running tftpd manually, e.g. not via xinetd, and see what the output is.  You can also try running it with `strace` to see exactly which files it is attempting to open and which systems calls it is making.

Double check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` to make sure traffic is being allowed into the server.

With respect to SELinux, depending on how your system is configured it may be logging to `/var/log/audit/audit.log` if you have enabled auditd.  See section 5 of [this page](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux).

Comment: Unfortunately I do have the -s flag set.  Reading files works just fine, so connectivity is functioning.  There is no /var/log/audit/audit.log.

Not familiar with strace - I guess that is the next thing to try.